# how can i create array with foreach in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i am trying to create array like in the example i wrote above:

```
$arr=array('roi sabah'=>500,yossi levi=>300,dana=>700);
```

but i want to create it dynamic with foreach.

how can i do it ?

thanks.

Comment: What do you want to create the array *from*? What's the input?

Comment: what do you have to start with? if you want to create this array from nothingness you aren't going to have less code than this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *access* an array with foreach (and optionally create another one while going through the array's values). But if you only have data like a name and a number from your example, not stored in an array, you can't use `foreach`.

Another way to create the array you mentioned:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['roi sabah'] = 500;
$arr['yossi levi'] = 300;
// etc
```

And to access these values:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  // $key is e.g. "roi sabah", and its value "500"
}
```